# Polymer - styling third party (non-Polymer) components

Tags: polymer

How does one create scoped styling of third party (non-Polymer) code?

I am working on wrapping the visjs timeline but the styles created inside my polymer wrapper element to style the timeline don't work because they are scoped. I have to modify global styles.

Is there a way to do local styling?

Comment: You could pierce the shadow-dom with the `/deep/` selector. See cross-scope styling, https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#xscope-styling

Comment: Ricky, as far as I can tell /deep/ is deprecated (chrome issues a warning).  But I finally understand why that selector exists.

Comment: Unfortunately that is the only way I could think of without actually editing the 3rd party library itself..

Answer (score 0):

Use the `::content` prefix in you're CSS, then you should be able to escape the scope and do a normal CSS.

Any ways, if this doesn't work. Can you provide the code ?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use one trick which is possible because of CSS specificity. It is very handy when You need to set styling on some element and do not want to put !important everywhere. In Your situation it could help also. Here is what I found that timeline looks like http://visjs.org/examples/timeline/styling/customCss.html Basically all styling is made in this example. So we have some div here with id

```
<div id="visualization"></div>
```

And inside of it all timeline is generated and it can be styled with a regular css like

```
.vis-timeline {
 /* some properties goes here */
}

.vis-item {
 /* some properties goes here */
}
...
```

But it can also van be styled using a little bit more specific selectors like this:

```
#visualization .vis-timeline {
 /* some properties goes here */
}

#visualization .vis-item {
 /* some properties goes here */
 color: red;
}
...
#second_visualization .vis-item {
 color: green;
 /* some properties goes here */
}
```

And then You can make as many different styles in one page as You like by changing the id and adding another selectors. In fact by using this kind of specificity You can style many web components out there - it is a super easy way of overriding any built in style - just add something more important into selector and You are good to go.

Comment: Another possibility would be to use something like `body .vis-timeline`; that way you don't need to use ids.